# How to rename range using VBA in excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I've 8+ yes professional programming experience in PHP and Java but none in VBA. Learning it right now.

I'm trying to make a Home budget sheet (Just for VBA learning purpose). For that, I'd done following

```
* In new excel (2007) file, rename sheet 1 as 'Forms' And Sheet2 as 'CatAcc'
* In sheet 'CatAcc', I'm using (planning) column A for categories and B for Account
* Row 1 is heading (A1 = "Categories", B1="Account"
* Using forms sheet (cell C2) & VBA button, I want to add a new category,
  sort it alphabetically and then rename range to add newly added row.
```

I wrote following code for that (Recorded testmacro to check how to name a range)

```
Sub AddCat_Click()
    'Copy data as last row
    Worksheets("CatAcc").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Worksheets("Forms").Cells(2, "C").Value

    'Find total Rows in categories
    Dim totalRows
    totalRows = Worksheets("CatAcc").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    'Define Range
    Dim rng
    rng = "A2:A" & totalRows
    'MsgBox rng

    'Select the range - Getting error in following line.
    Worksheets("CatAcc").Range(rng).Select

    'Name the range
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="categories", RefersToR1C1:="=CatAcc!R2C1:R3C1"

    'Sort range alphabetically

    'Apply range as drop-down options
End Sub
Sub testmacro()
    Range("A2:A3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="categories", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=CatAcc!R2C1:R3C1"
End Sub
```

While selecting the range, I got following error

```
Run-time error '1004'
Select method of Range class failed
```

I'm unable to understand what that error mean and why I'm getting that by just adding worksheet name.

Again, What does following line mean? What is happening there? I could not understand meaning of R2C1:R3C2. This values came from recorded macro when I named A2:A3 cells as 'categories'

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="categories", RefersToR1C1:="=CatAcc!R2C1:R3C1"
```

Comment: You should declare your variables with specific types, e.g., `Dim rng as String` and `Dim totalRows as Long`, etc.  Although this does not address your problem, it would be a good habit to start as you begin to learn VBA.

Comment: The `R2C1:R3C1` means Row2/Column1 to Row3/Column2, or in other words, the same as "A2:A3", just a different way of writing it. (I personally prefer using the A1 reference style to the R1C1)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @DavidZemens I agree any bad habit should be stopped as early as possible. I'll keep your point in mind in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to select the range `Range("A2:A3").Select`. The `"=CatAcc!R2C1:R3C1"` in the next line is automatically taking care of it.

**Explanation**

"=CatAcc!R2C1:R3C1"

1. CatAcc is the Sheet where the range is
2. R2C1 means Row 2 Col 1 which is nothing but A2
3. Similarly R3C1 is Row 3 Col 1 which is nothing but A3

So the above can also be written as

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add NAME:="categories", RefersTo:="=CatAcc!$A$2:$A$3"
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Sidd.
My bad I could not understand it as row/col. New thing for me.

Comment: You are welcome :). You might also want to check out R1C1 notation in MSDN?

Comment: See R1C1 Reference Style here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee264226%28v=office.12%29.aspx (Midway down the page)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm going through it, ebooks, internet tutorials etc. Need to learn a lot for VBA basics.
CAn you suggest best way to learn VBA?

Comment: See this post by @brettdj: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523102/what-is-the-best-way-to-master-vba-macros-for-ms-office-applications/7524173#7524173